# Django Aggregate with several models

Tags: django

I have these models :

```
class Package(models.Model):
    title = CharField(...)

class Item(models.Model)
    package = ForeignKey(Package)
    price = FloatField(...)

class UserItem(models.Model)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    item = ForeignKey(Item)
    purchased = BooleanField()
```

I am trying to achieve 2 functionality with the best performance possible :

1. In my templete I would like to calculate each package price sum of all its items. (Aggregate I assume ?)
2. More complicated : I wish that for each user I can sum up the price of all item purchased. so the purchased = True.

Assume I have 10 items in one package which each of them cost 10$ the package sum should be 100$. assume the user purchase 5 items the second sum should be 50$.

I can easily do simple queries with templetetags but I believe it can be done better ? (Hopefully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To total the price for a specific package `a_package` you can use this code

```
Item.objects.filter(package=a_package).aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

There is a [a guide on how to do these kind of queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), and the [aggregate documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions) with all the different functions described.

This kind of query can also solve your second problem.

```
UserItem.objects.filter(user=a_user).filter(purchased=True).aggregate(sum('price'))
```

You can also use `annotate()` to attach the count to each object, see the first link above.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful ! Does the SUM aggregate functionality doesn't have serious performance penalty ? Assuming there are no more the 20 items per aggregation ?

Comment: This is the way Django expects you to do it, and will be handled by the Django SQL generation, so I doubt there is a way of doing it faster that wouldn't require a lot of extra work to implement, if at all. For 20 items you should certainly be fine.

Comment: Unless you got thousands of items and hundred of users simultaneously on your website, performance is the least of your problems @Nuno

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way *in my opinion* would be to define a method `total` on the Model class and decorate it as a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property). This will return the `total` (using Django ORM's [Sum aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)) for either `Package` or `User`.

Example for class `Package`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

...

class Package(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.item_set.aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

In your template code you would use `total` as any other model attribute. E.g.:

```
{{ package_instance.total }}
```

Comment: This is a good addition to @vic solution, although if you are looking for perfs, making a real model atrtibut and a signal to populate it will yield better results.

Comment: @e-satis Valuable comment + answer, +1ed.

Comment: I like this idea, however I am afraid that this can cause django to make two queries to the database instead of one. Assuming I am passing an annotate package list from my view to my templete this will all be done in one query. however , If I'll send over all packages and within the tempelte call my model function it may cause the query to split. Am I wrong here ? Also why do I need it with the @property decorator ?

Comment: @Nuno_147 `@property` for elegance's sake, so that you can access it as a property from your code, not just your template. Unsure about the total DB hits, depends on how you'll use it. Utilize [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/) if you have perf probs, but do recall that **premature optimization is evil**.

Comment: I am coming from kernel development so I am taking care of performance. never heard that prematur eoptiization is evil :) maybe I should adopt that :)

Comment: @Nuno_147 It surely is when using a high-level framework like Django. Btw, the exact quote is **premature optimization is the root of all evil**, by [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Answer (score 3):

@Vic Smith got the solution.

But I would add a `price` attribute on the `package` model if you wish

> the best performance possible

You would add a `on_save` signal to Item, and if created, you update the related `package` object.

This way you can get the package price very quickly, and even make quick sorting, comparing, etc.

Plus, I don't really get the purpose of the `purchased` attribute. But you probably want to make a ManyToMany relationship between `Item` and `User`, and define `UserItem` as the connection with the `trhough` parameter.

Anyway, my experience is that you usually want to make a relationship between `Item` and a `Purchasse` objet, which is linked to `User`, and not a direct link (unless you start to get performances issues...). Having `Purchasse` as a record of the event "the user bough this and that" make things easier to handle.

Comment: this is just an example of something I am trying to do. These are no realy models. I just tried to give an idea of what I am trying to do. the purchased model doesn't really exists.